# Cannot import name 'threshold' from scipy.stats

Tags: python, import, scipy, threshold, scipy.stats

I am trying to use function `threshold` from `scipy` package.

```
from scipy.stats import threshold
I_t=threshold(I, threshmin=2, threshmax=400, newval=-1) # I is an array containing image data
```

However, i am getting an error message saying

> cannot import name 'threshold' from 'scipy.stats'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `threshold` was [deprecated in SciPy 0.17.0](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/release.0.17.0.html#deprecated-features) and [removed from SciPy 1.0.0](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/release.1.0.0.html#backwards-incompatible-changes).  Use [`numpy.clip`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) (with arguments adjusted appropriately) instead.

Comment: Thank you, this helps. But, the `numpy.clip(array;a_min,a_max)` will replace all the values lower than `a_min` to `a_min`, I would prefer to make it `zero` instead of having `a_min`